# Wordpress conditionals

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP/Wordpress conditionals question i'd like to throw out:

What's the functional difference between these conditionals below?

[image]

These two sets of conditional statements to my eyes seem equivalent. However, only the one under // Works functions as expected.

I would say the top is saying, "If not X or not Y, then do something".

The bottom one is saying "If X or Y, do nothing, otherwise, do something".

Seems like two ways of saying the same thing? When I am ON the blank-template.php using the second conditional, it correctly "does nothing". If I am ON the blank-template with the first conditional, it's still echoing out the FL builder footer.

Comment: please share code

Comment: First one should use `&&` not `||`

Comment: Here's an example of why it should be `&&`: https://3v4l.org/DSWbb

Answer (score 0):

One thing i cant understand why you put double bracket in the both of code.

For eg.

```
if ( !is_page_template('template-file.php') || !is_page_template('another -template-file.php') {
   // Write your code here
}
```

It should be work for you. Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

use below code for If statement

```
 if ( !is_page_template('blank-template.php') || !is_page_template('blank-adwords-landing-page.php')) {
     echo do_shortcode('[fl_builder_insert_layout slug="global-footer"]');
    }
```